# Python Regex - not catching non-alphanumerics

Tags: python, regex

trying to check for properly formatted name string before returning it as an exercise in regex. It catches strings such as

> 'bob1' '55bob' 'b64ob' etc.

But will not catch non-alphanumeric input such as `bob!`. I had thought that the `[a-z]+` part would take care of that, looking through the documentation. I must be overlooking something, any help?  Thanks.

```
def get_name(self):
    """Returns the user-name if valid"""

    match_obj = re.match(r'\b[a-z]+\b', self.name, re.I)
    if match_obj is None: 
        raise ValueError('Matching name not found')
    return self.name
```

Comment: removed my answer, if you want users to input only alphanumeric, then `^[a-zA-90-9]+$`, with re.I `^[a-z0-9]+$` or with underscore `^\w+$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A boundary `\b` looks for the beginning or end of a sequence of `\w` characters. To get some sense of what a `\w` character is you can see.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.match('\w+', 'bob!')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 3), match='bob'>
>>> re.match('\w+', "there's")
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 5), match='there'>
```

It matches letters but not punctuation. So back to your regex `\b[a-z]+\b`. If I'm to draw the boundary around `bob!` in curly braces it will look like `{bob}!`. So the regex indeed matches with the result `bob`.

That is an explanation of what's making your regex behave the way it does. But it's not clear how to answer your question since you haven't told us what you want it to do. Assuming you want to check if the string contains `a-z` and `A-Z` and *nothing else* I would echo the recommendation to use `^[a-z]+$`. Here, `^` marks the beginning of the string and `$` marks the end.

Answer (score 2):

To only allow names consisting of alphabetic letters (which I think is what you are asking, I may be wrong) ...

```
def get_name(self):
    """Returns the user-name if valid"""

    match_obj = re.search(r'^[a-z]+$', self.name, re.I)
    if match_obj is None: 
        raise ValueError('Matching name not found')
    return self.name
```

In this case, errors will be raised for any of `bo1b`, `bob!`, `2bob` etc

Answer (score 2):

```
match_obj = re.match(r'\b[a-z]+$', self.name, re.I)
```

`match` starts from `start` of string and compares and gives a match if it can match 0 or more characters from start.To make a complete match use `$` instead of `\b` .